# Selecting nan values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, select

I have a shapefile of a lot of polygons. I calculated perimeter of each polygon and some polygons returned `nan` values as they have hole/ring. I am looking for a way to select the polygons with 'nan' value in QGIS. `"column_name" = 'nan'` seems to be an invalid expression in QGIS.

How do I select them?

Comment: Select the ones greater than 0 and invert selection? NaN is *not a number* so shouldn't be greater than 0 (or less than or equal to).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: having a hole should not break the perimeter calculation, more likely those polygons are invalid

Comment: Thanks Ian, you are right. Actually these polygons have been converted from raster image. I simplified the polygons, so there is no nan values anymore.

Comment: better than simplifie, may be the processing called "Fix"

Comment: I tried Fix, but it didn't solve.